# Using my own server for uploading files in Outsystem

Tags: server, outsystems

I am currently working in outsystems. I have an interface there which allows end users to upload files. But its getting uploaded to the Outsystem server, is there a way I can upload files to my own file server

I couldn't find any setting where I can change the server

Comment: If your file server is setup to add files from a remote location then you can. How to do this depends on your fileserver. For ftp acces for example you can use a ftp plugin from the forge. You can get the file binary from the [upload widget](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/11/Developing_an_Application/Design_UI/Inputs/Enable_End_Users_to_Upload_Files).
To be able to give a complete answer we would need more information. Are you using traditional, reactive, mobole? How you want to connect to your own file server?

Comment: I want the files to be uploaded to a drive or a local server when the users upload files through the interface

Comment: If you want to store it on the local drive or a network share you can use the [filesystem](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-overview/68/filesystem) module on the outsystems forge.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your file server I guess. Personally I upload files to a OneDrive using [Microsoft's graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). With this I am able to send binary data that I've uploaded via the OutSystems widget to this specific OneDrive. This works in traditional, reactive and mobile for as far as my experience goes.

Also, as mentioned before, the [FileSystem](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-overview/68/filesystem) extension from the forge is generally pretty useful for this kind of stuff.